# Spring Boot validation with Hibernate Validator

Tags: validation, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Anyone know if it`s possible to create one method in my entity, to execute when I put the annotation @Valid in my class?

Example:

I have this Object:

```
public class Area {
    @NotEmpty
    private String unidade;
    @NotNull
    private double tamanho;

    public String getUnidade() {
        return unidade;
    }

    public void setUnidade(String unidade) {
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }

    public double getTamanho() {
        return tamanho;
    }

    public void setTamanho(double tamanho) {
        this.tamanho = tamanho;
    }
}
```

And I have this method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/recolhimento")
public class RecolhimentoController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public boolean getRecolhimento(@Valid Area area){
        ...
    }
}
```

so when I call this method the Spring Boot will validate my model Area( but I want to create one method that will be execute when I use @Valid.

it`s possible? how?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You want to know how to work with `@Valid` or you want to programmatically determine whether or not an object is valid?

Comment: how the @Valid work I know. I want to know how can I create one method in my model that will be executed when I put one "Valid" in my method :D

Comment: Let's take a step back, what is it *actually*, in terms of functionality, that you want to achieve? Knowing that will help to provide a meaningful answer. Just putting `@Valid` somewhere will not cause any methods to be executed. It's the opposite: When calling methods with `@Valid` on managed objects such as CDI or Spring beans, this will trigger validation of the annotated parameters or the return value.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.

You can find examples in this project: https://github.com/malkusch/validation

Comment: Those are custom validators, I don't think that's what the OP asked. Also, this is a link only answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer